# Specifying the ']' character in a C/C++ scanf() scanset

Tags: c++, c, format, scanf

I would like to use a scanf family function to extract a string delimited by ']'. 
For a delimiter of ')' one can do this:

```
scanf(" %80[^)]", &buf);
```

But how do you include the ']' in the scanset in general (not just the negated set case example above)? Is there some kind of escape seq for that?

```
"[^\\]]"
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to put ']' as the first character in the pattern:

```
scanf(" %80[^]]", &buf);
```

Comment: But this is not a general answer -- it might work in this particular case but in the non-negated case how do you specify that character in the scan set?

Comment: Oh I just found the spec for that and you are right that the first character in the scan-set is handled specially and it will accept the ] character even in a non-negated set. It certainly feels a bit 'hacky' to define a feature like that!!